# Extend swap! behaviour for nil type in Clojure

Tags: clojure

let suppose, I have var atom-var

```
(def atom-val (atom []))
```

Also suppose a standard behaviour of atom:

```
(swap! atom-val conj {:b "2"})
=> #object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x6500d3fd {:status :ready, :val [{:a "2"}]
(@atom-val)
=> #object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x6500d3fd {:status :ready, :val [{:a "2"}]
```

I want to create the same behaviour as it would work with nil object, but without actions:

```
(def atom-val nil)
(swap! atom-val conj "New val")
```

Of course, I will get a NullPointerException. But I want that nothing happened, supress it. I do not need to write try every time it, I just need the described behavuiour.

I see that *swap!* is a function, *atom* is a function, atom returns *clojure.lang.IAtom*, clojure.lang.IAtom is an interface. I cannot extend interface. 
How can I get the described behaviour?

Well, I have a global dynamic variable which is equal to nil

```
(def ^:dynamic  atom-val nil).
```

Whenever a thread is created (it's ring handler with compojure), I am binding atom-val to

```
(defn func [handler] 
   (fn [request]
     (binding [atom-val (atom [])]
        (handler request)
    )
 )
```

So, I have such a form in different functions:

```
(swap! atom-val conj "New val").
```

I can run it everywhere lots of times (inside/outside different functions). It's really bad to check every time whether **atom-val** is null or not. Functions **have** to make *swap!*, but sometimes *atom-val* cannot be initialized properly (when a function makes swap! outside ring handlers, before binding).

So I decided to do it this way: I'd like to extend *swap!* protocol for Atom and when nil (when `atom-val` is *nil*) is passed it mustn't throw NullPointerException.

Comment: May one inquire what is the purpose of this substitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an atom that does nothing, you can write:

```
(def noop-atom
  (reify clojure.lang.IAtom
    (reset [_ _])
    (swap [_ _])
    (swap [_ _ _])
    (swap [_ _ _ _])
    (swap [_ _ _ _ _])
    (compareAndSet [_ _ _])))
```

You can then use this atom as the root-value of the dynamic var.

If your goal is to manage state during the lifecycle of a Ring request/response, you can write a custom [middleware](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Concepts#middleware).

Comment: Thanks, you have given a correct answer. Then I found also deref protocol.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `fnil`.  See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fnil

Example:

```
(def atom-val nil)
(def nil-swap! (fnil swap! (atom [])))

(nil-swap! atom-val conj "New val") => ["New val"]
```

And don't forget to keep a browser tab open to [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) at all times!

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to `swap!` on a nil? I'm not sure what you meant with actions and doing nothing.

It definitely doesn't make sense (at least to me) to `swap!` a nil value; if it does to you, you should review what atoms really are. Perhaps you mean that when given a nil instead of an atom reference the `swap!` wouldn't do anything.

If so then you can just make your own function to do that check for you:

```
(defn nilable-swap!
  [a f]
  (when a (swap! a f)))
```

*But* I really don't recommend you do that, if this is what you want to do, it's an indication of bad design and control flow. Of course, it does make sense to check if your atom reference is nil if you're not sure, but do you really need to routinely check that? is there truly no point in which you know you got your atom reference?

I *think* I might have answered your question but if I misunderstood, feel free to clarify and I'll update/delete the answer.